# Android, dynamic Listview layout changing on scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, custom-adapter, custom-lists

I have a conversation mode in my application where I wish to load one layout for one user and another layout for the other. It need not always be alternating hence I cannot use a simple "%2" to achieve it.
Based on a flag I am assigning a dynamic layout, which works. My problem is that as I scroll the layouts get distorted as in, conversation of user_1 will get layout_2 or conversation of user_2 will get layout_1, absolutely random.

I did something similar to an answer I saw here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16774696/4810718

There were a few posts about randomized data. That is not my issue, the order of the list items does not change however the layout get's randomly applied. I read that the items in view + 1 are kept in temporary memory, regarding this another thing I noticed was: as I keep adding items such that the scrollbar comes into picture when I add a second item outside the visibility it tends to get the layout of the topmost item (first item) visible. Scrolling would later give me seemingly randomized results.

```
public class ConversationAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<ConversationContent> objects;
    ImageView user;
    static int ind = 0;

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        TextView textView3;
    }

    public ConversationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ConversationContent> objects)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public ConversationContent getItem(int position)
    {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            if (Main_Page3.convFlag == 1)
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_item_1, null);
            }
            else
            {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_item_2, null);
            }

            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trans);
            holder.textView1.setTypeface(Main_Activity.fontC);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lang);
            holder.textView2.setTypeface(Main_Activity.fontC);
            holder.textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            holder.textView3.setTypeface(Main_Activity.fontC);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();     
        }

        holder.textView1.setText(objects.get(position).getTranslatedText());
        holder.textView2.setText(objects.get(position).getTranslationString());
        SpannableString originalTextString = new SpannableString("\n" + objects.get(position).getOriginalText());
        originalTextString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 0, originalTextString.length(), 0);
        holder.textView1.append(originalTextString);
        holder.textView3.setText(objects.get(position).getUser());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

So, that's the code I've written. A possible solution I thought of was if I used an array of views and loaded them accordingly, it may work? I'm really not really sure how I should be going about doing this - I'm still pretty new to Android.
I've searched a bit but could not get a helpful solution. Please direct me to a helpful solution you find or, a working answer would be most appreciable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to put the flag to determine which layout to use on your `ConversationContent` object, then override `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)` something like this:

```
@Override
int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (objects.get(position).isReply()) {  //isReply can be whatever you want to determine whether to change layout
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (getItemViewType(position) == 1)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_item_1, null);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation_item_2, null);
        }

        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trans);
        holder.textView1.setTypeface(Main_Activity.fontC);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lang);
        holder.textView2.setTypeface(Main_Activity.fontC);
        holder.textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user);
        holder.textView3.setTypeface(Main_Activity.fontC);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();     
    }

    holder.textView1.setText(objects.get(position).getTranslatedText());
    holder.textView2.setText(objects.get(position).getTranslationString());
    SpannableString originalTextString = new SpannableString("\n" + objects.get(position).getOriginalText());
    originalTextString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 0, originalTextString.length(), 0);
    holder.textView1.append(originalTextString);
    holder.textView3.setText(objects.get(position).getUser());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much better than a crude method which I had no certainty of working. Did just what you suggested, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
For listview adapter, if you want to show different layout,
```

like conversion mode. you would better override the following two methods:

```
//set your layout type here

public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return 0;
}

//the layout count in your adapter

public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 0;
}


Here is an example you can refer to:

public class ChatMessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<ChatMessage> mDatas;

    public ChatMessageAdapter(Context context, List<ChatMessage> mDatas)
    {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mDatas = mDatas;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mDatas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return mDatas.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = mDatas.get(position);
        if (chatMessage.getType() == Type.INCOMING)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ChatMessage chatMessage = mDatas.get(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {

            if (getItemViewType(position) == 0)
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_from_msg, parent,
                        false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.mDate = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id_form_msg_date);
                viewHolder.mMsg = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id_from_msg_info);
            } else
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_to_msg, parent,
                        false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.mDate = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id_to_msg_date);
                viewHolder.mMsg = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.id_to_msg_info);
            }
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //set data here
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        viewHolder.mDate.setText(df.format(chatMessage.getDate()));
        viewHolder.mMsg.setText(chatMessage.getMsg());
        return convertView;
    }

    private final class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView mDate;
        TextView mMsg;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but as it was already suggested in the the answer above I accepted that one.